# Creating a listener using android AIDL?

Tags: android, listener, aidl

I have designed a service using AIDL in system service ,which is called by the client process to perform certain calculation and return their desired output but now I have to add a listener which must be implemented by on certain events, like if **Event X occurs eg a list of resources are updated then client will implement `onResourceChanged` Listener** . So I need a sample design for how to proceed? 
PS : I took reference of **PhoneStateListener** but still didn't got what I am looking for

Comment: pass another AIDL interface (callback) in some of your AIDL call, like: `register(callback_aidl_object)`

Comment: Please share more details about implementation

Comment: see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/IRemoteServiceCallback.aidl

Answer (score 0):

You can implement call backs in AIDL and **Observer Pattern** can be created with these AIDL calls and interfaces.

I've answered this in another post, Please refer to :

[AIDL Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948671/how-can-i-use-aidl-remote-service-to-deal-with-defferent-clients-concurrent-req/34217138#34217138)