# Aidl result via callback

Tags: android, aidl

I have written an application which records some audio signal. This signal has to be processed by a plug-in which is installed on my device. For the communication between the main application and the plug-in, we use an aidl interface.

As I am new to those interfaces, I wonder if the following would work for the plug-in to return a result to my main application:

I created an interface:

```
public interface MainAppCallback {
    public void onResult(String result);
}
```

I implement it in my **recording thread**:

```
MainAppCallback callback = new MainAppCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(String result) {
        // Add result to member variable of recording thread
    }
};
```

In my **aidl interface**, I defined the methods for the plug-in:

```
/** Callback to send results to main application
*/
void registerCallback(MainAppCallback callback);

/** The code is documentation enough
*/
void unregisterCallback();
```

I then want to do something like this in my **recording thread**:

```
PlugIn.registerCallback(callback);
```

Is this the correct way to go, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Previously answered and complete code structure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34217138/3451697

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct. Make sure you have defined an aidl file for the callback interface too.

here is an answer here which already has an example of the 2 aidl files you need to have for callbacks :
[Android remote service callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592990/android-remote-service-callbacks)

There is also complete sample code here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html